# the number of characters in an input text field

Tags: omnistudio

How can find the number of characters in an input text field is less than 3, and show a message in the flex card as an error.  If more than 3 characters proceed with the action functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the "Minimum Length" property of the Input Text Field to 3. The Text Field will then show an error message which says that the provided value is too short:

[image]

Note that while the error message does display, it won't stop any action from being taken if the user ignores it.

I would recommend that data capture processes be done using an Omniscript rather than a Flexcard. An Omniscript has a lot more functionality when it comes to data validation and surfacing of error messages to the user.

Good luck!